# Polygonal paths and polygons with prescribed set of vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

Let $A$ be a finite set of points in the plane. How can we determine if there is a simple open polygonal path (i.e. without intersections),  whose vertices are exactly $A$, with no straight angles between adjacent sides?   Since in  [mathoverflow.net/q/226469/4312](http://mathoverflow.net/q/226469/4312) question is  only about cycles,  the stronger question also remains. Namely - how  to determine if there exists a polygon with non-intersecting sides and  without straight angles, whose vertices are exacly $A$ ?

Particular interesting case is when $A$ is a set of points $(x;y)$ with $0\leq x+y \leq 2n$ , where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers. Hypothesis : no for path for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Such an $n$-gon exists always provided the points don't lie on one line. Suppose that there are $3$ points  $p, q, r\in A$ that don't lie on one line. Take a generic  point  $O$ inside the triangle $pqr$, such that no line containing two points from $A$ passes through $O$. Once you do this, you can enumerate all the points of $A$ in the anti-clockwise order with respect to $O$, $A=p_1,\ldots, p_n$. Then you join each $p_i$ with $p_{i+1}$ by a segment (and $p_n$ with $p_1$). This will clearly give you the desired $n$-gon.

Comment: @Dmitri I don't know whether a point counts as a vertex if the angle there is a straight angle.

Comment: @Gerry, I see. If such a point doesn't count, the answer will be considerably more involved indeed (I don't know the answer for such a version of the question). I guess, Algirdas should add this information to the question if he wants to exclude this type of vertices.

Comment: duplicate https://mathoverflow.net/q/226469/4312

Comment: Fedor, since the modified question is now asking the angles not to be straight, this is not a duplicate. This version if obviously harder.

Comment: Take  A 15 points  (x;y)   with   $0\leq x+y \leq 4$ . It seems,  that there isn't such a broken line.  But how  to  prove  this ?

Comment: P.S.   $x , y$  are nonnegative  integers

Comment: I agree that your example of the fifteen points does not have a broken line, but I don’t see a clean proof.

Comment: I conject,  that if we take any even number instead of 4 in the example,  the answer remains negative.  It's interesting  to which even numbers computer could check.

Comment: I conjecture that there are only finitely many even numbers for which the given configuration does not have a path. Further, one can do a breadth first search to find such a path. Since you ask for no intersecting lines, you can reduce consider a divide and conquer algorithm by choosing successive vertices as midpoints of the end path. I don't know how fast it will be. Gerhard "Computer Can Handle Size Six" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: Is "a broken line" what would normally be called a (closed) simple polygon (an -gon as per @Dmitri), or is it instead an open, simple polygonal path? The term "broken line" does not have a standard definition in the (English) literature.

Comment: @M. Winter. In the given example, A for fixed n∈N, consists of (n+1)(2n+1) points with nonnegative integer coordinates.  But you can't move them arbitrarily.  Look,  please,  at the pictures  of J.O'Rourke, below.

Comment: For n=1, Joseph has a diagram of impossibility. Likely a more complicated one exists for n=2. However, there is a path for n=3 and thus for all higher n. Break into the union of a central point and 3 of (n=3/2) size triangles with overlap. One has a path from the center filling the triangles in a cyclic order, and can end on an external vertex. Gerhard "Seeing Spots Before My Eyes" Paseman, 2019.12.07.

Answer (score 5):

The following polygon is a counterexample to the hypothesis for $n=4$. Namely we consider the set of integer  points $(x,y)|0\le x+y\le 8$. The picture is on a square-lined paper, where the size of one square is $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}$

The picture was constructed in collaboration with Svetlana Ermakova.

So my guess that it will be possible to do the same thing for all $n\ge 4$

[image]

Comment: Nice! And this is a closed cycle, a simple polygon.

Comment: Congratulations - nice work :) So - is the n=4 the smallest possible - what about n=3 ?

Comment: @AlgirdasRugys: For $n=3$, there is a polygonal path (but maybe not a polygon). I added a figure to my post.

Comment: Me too, I don't see for a while whether such a polygon exists for $n=3$. I would give more than 50% chance that it doesn't. But I have not thought yet how to prove it, just made about 100 unsuccessful pictures...

Comment: Nice path,  Joseph.  So it seems, here are  questions for  $0 \leq x+y \leq 4$  for path and  $0 \leq x+y \leq 6$  for a polygon.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, just an illustration for $6$ points, $0 \le x+y \le 2$.

---

[image: Poly3]

---

- $A,B,C$: Point $3$ cannot connect to $1$ or $6$, so it must connect to
  $2,5$ or $4,5$ or $2,4$.
- $B$: Point $6$ is now isolated by $34$ from $1$ and $2$.
- $C$: Point $1$ is now isolated by $34$ from $5$ and $6$.
- $D$: $1$ is trapped.
- $E$: $2$ is trapped.

---

**(Later.)**
Here is a simple polygonal path through the $28$ lattice points
$0 \le x+y \le 6$:

---

[image: Path6]

Comment: You can reduce this to whether a path ends at vertex 1 or not. When it doesn't, symmetry gives two cases that are easily checked.  A slow divide and conquer algorithm can handle the general problem in a similar way. Gerhard "Knows No Fast Algorithm Yet" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: What does it mean for a path to end at a vertex, when the path must be a closed cycle?

Comment: I interpret a broken line as a broken line segment, which has the (topological) shape of a path, not of a cycle. Gerhard "Who Sometimes Does Not Return" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Ah, and I was assuming a "broken line" is a polygon. Your interpretation may be the correct one. Clearly there is confusion over this issue.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The OP clarified---Your interpretation is what he intended, mine was incorrect. Still my example shows there is no simple polygonal path through those $6$ points, turning at each.

Comment: By affine invariance ,  the poster's suggested configuration is equivalent to the problem on a triangular grid. There one has that an extreme vertex must  not be an endpoint, and with k=2 one has two cases to check, both of which isolate a vertex under the conditions.  Gerhard "Let Symmetry Do The Work" Paseman, 2019.12.06.

Comment: You could add: This path can be extended with a sawtooth pattern on each pair of rows below it, showing that there are appropriate paths on any larger triangles with even side lengths.

Answer (score 2):

This paper addresses similar (but I don't think identical) questions.
In any case, a key search phrase is *covering path*.

> Dumitrescu, Adrian, Dániel Gerbner, Balázs Keszegh, and Csaba D. Tóth. "Covering paths for planar point sets." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 51, no. 2 (2014): 462-484. [Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-013-9563-4).

[image: DGKT]

---

What appears to be unique is the OP's insistence that there is a turn
at every vertex--no collinearities.
Of course, if the points are in general position, there is
automatically a turn at every vertex.

---

[image]

          

<sup>Fig.2</sup>

---